# proof about an polynomial proposition.

Tags: polynomials

Welcome to edit my post to revise any mistakes, especially English, thanks.

---

**Proposition**

Assuming $f(x),g(x)$ are integer polynomials, and $g(x)$ is primitive.

If $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, where $h(x)$ is rational polynomial, then $h(x)$ must be polynomial with integer coefficients.

---

**Proof:**

$f(x)=g(x)h(x)=g(x)a h_1(x)=a g(x)h_1(x)=a f_1(x)$,

where $a$ is rational number and $h_1(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ are primitive polynomials.

If $a$ is not an integer number, then $f(x)$ should not be an integer polynomial which lead to contradiction with the assumption.

so $h(x)$ must be integer polynomial.

Comment: Are you asking if your proof is correct?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, I am not sure. English's problems are also welcome to edit.

Comment: It looks fine yet (1) I'd love to see a little (little!) more explanation why $\,a\notin\Bbb Z\implies f(x)\,$ is not an integer polynomial, and (2) you may also want to describe a little more how is $\,a\,$ obtained: you assume at least one coefficient of $\,h(x)\,$ isn't integer, so in order to get $\,h_1(x)\,$ you first must "take out" acommon denominator of all those coefficients of $\,h(x)\,$ to get an integer pol., and then you take out a common divisor of all the coefficients to make it primitive...etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio yeah, 2)I obtain $a$ just consider it an common denominator to get primitive $h_1(x)$, but without the thought of assuming at least one coefficient of h(x) isn't integer, your suggestion is useful. 1)$a\notin \mathbb{Z}$ so get an rational poly $\text{fNew}(x)\neq f(x)$

Comment: @HyperGroups I concur with Don, you certianly need to justify the claim (1). I cannot parse the reason given above.

Comment: @KeyIdeas well,Don say a litte more.... I wonder if this is enough. a not belongs to Z, a belongs to Q, so a=r/s, s not equal to 1, and (r,s)=1, f_1 does not have common denominator s, so $a f_1$ with rational coefficients.